# What is the & in 2>&1

Tags: batch-file, io-redirection, handle

What is is meaning of 2>&1?

I know what it does but why the '&' construct? I've been telling myself that &1 is the device/filename of handle 1. This works for me but I would really like to know the justification for ampersand, if there is one.

Ampersand has other meanings - multi-commands on one line and a special form of pipe &&). It's hard to see how these relate to the handle name (&1)

Is it simply a character that says this is a device file handle?

Comment: `>&` is the syntax to redirect one handle to another, or more precisely, to redirect a handle to the location the other one currently points to. These two characters are a unit and constitute a single redirection operator. I cannot tell why this syntax has been chosen – for that you would have to ask Microsoft…

Comment: I suppose it was just copied by Microsoft from the Unix world. The syntax is really old

Comment: Thanks, aschfl. That's a definitive name for the redirection operator '>&'.  I've looked high and low for that. Now I can rest.

Comment: Hi Jeb, Yes, the syntax IS really old and also hard to put into spoken words. Aschipfl's explanation is a great help for me who doesn't have a Unix background, For my own purposes I will call it, Redirect to handle and it's counterpart, Redirect from handle. Thanks for bolstering my knowledge.